# How to fix java.lang.StackoverflowError

Tags: java, user-interface, stack-overflow

I'm not sure what the problem with this code is but whenever I run it I get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. How would I fix it? This is what is displayed in the output console of netbeans:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)  at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
```

code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Nicholas Ferretti
 */
public class Section2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Section2 s2Frame = new Section2();
    Section3 s3Frame = new Section3();

    ResultSet section2Questions;
    DB connection = new DB();

    /**
     * Creates new form Section2Question1
     */
    TimerFrame timerFrame;
    int timeRemaining = 60;
    int s2QuestionNumber = 1;

    public Section2() {
        this.timerFrame = new TimerFrame(this);
        initComponents();
        groupButton();
        section2QuestionBox.setEditable(false);
        s2QuestionNumberLabel.setText("Question "+s2QuestionNumber+":");

        try {
            section2Questions=connection.queryTbl("SELECT * FROM tblQuestions WHERE Section = 2");
            section2Questions.next();
            String firstQuestion = section2Questions.getString("Questions");
            System.out.println(firstQuestion);
            section2QuestionBox.setText(firstQuestion);

            String firstAnswers = section2Questions.getString("AllPossibleAnswers");
            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(firstAnswers).useDelimiter(",");
            while(scLine.hasNext()){
            String answer1 = scLine.next();
            S2Answer1.setText(answer1);
                System.out.println(answer1);
            String answer2 = scLine.next();
            S2Answer2.setText(answer2);
                System.out.println(answer2);
            String answer3 = scLine.next();
            S2Answer3.setText(answer3);
                System.out.println(answer3);
            String answer4 = scLine.next();
            S2Answer4.setText(answer4);
                System.out.println(answer4);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Section1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Error with SQL firstQuestion");
        }

        /*boolean t = timerFrame.timer(Section2Timer, timeRemaining);
        if(t == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Time up for section.");
        s2Frame.setVisible(false);
        //s3Frame.setVisible(true);
        }*/
    }

    private void groupButton() {
        ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup();

        buttons.add(S2Answer2);
        buttons.add(S2Answer3);
        buttons.add(S2Answer1);
        buttons.add(S2Answer4);
    }

    private void timer() {
        try {
            Score time = new Score();
            int timeRemaining = time.getTime();
            while(timeRemaining>0){
                Section2Timer.setText(timeRemaining+"");
                Section2Timer.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 32));
                Section2Timer.setForeground(Color.RED);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                timeRemaining--;
                if(timeRemaining==0){
                    time.setTime(60);

                }
                time.setTime(timeRemaining);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    // handle the exception...        
            // For example consider calling Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); here.
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        s2QuestionNumberLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        section2QuestionBox = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        S2Answer1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        S2Answer2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        S2Answer3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        S2Answer4 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        nextS2Question = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Section2Timer = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("SECTION 2:");

        s2QuestionNumberLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        s2QuestionNumberLabel.setText("QUESTION 1:");

        jLabel9.setText("Answers:");

        section2QuestionBox.setColumns(20);
        section2QuestionBox.setRows(5);
        section2QuestionBox.setText("At a conference, 12 memeber shook hands with each other \nbefore & after the meeting. How many total number of\nhand shakes occurred?");
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(section2QuestionBox);

        S2Answer1.setText("Monday");
        S2Answer1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                S2Answer1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        S2Answer2.setText("Tuesday");
        S2Answer2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                S2Answer2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        S2Answer3.setText("Wednesday");
        S2Answer3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                S2Answer3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        S2Answer4.setText("Friday");
        S2Answer4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                S2Answer4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        nextS2Question.setText("Next");
        nextS2Question.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nextS2QuestionActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(125, 125, 125)
                                .addComponent(s2QuestionNumberLabel)))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(217, 217, 217)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(S2Answer1)
                                .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                                .addComponent(S2Answer2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(S2Answer3)
                                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                                .addComponent(S2Answer4))
                            .addComponent(nextS2Question, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addGap(139, 139, 139)
                .addComponent(Section2Timer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(Section2Timer, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(0, 0, 0)
                .addComponent(s2QuestionNumberLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(S2Answer1)
                    .addComponent(S2Answer2)
                    .addComponent(S2Answer3)
                    .addComponent(S2Answer4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 140, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(nextS2Question)
                .addGap(125, 125, 125))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    String answer = "";
    private void S2Answer1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        answer = S2Answer1.getText();
    }                                         

    private void S2Answer2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        answer = S2Answer2.getText();
    }                                         

    private void S2Answer3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        answer = S2Answer3.getText();
    }                                         

    private void S2Answer4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        answer = S2Answer4.getText();
    }                                         

    private void nextS2QuestionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        Score score = new Score();

        try {
            String actualAnswer = section2Questions.getString("Answer");
            int currentScore = score.getS2Score();
            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(actualAnswer)){
            currentScore+=5;
            score.setS2Score(currentScore);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Section1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Error in Next Question method");
        }

        if(s2QuestionNumber ==4){
            int timeLeft = score.getTime();
            int currentBonusPoints = score.getBonusPoints();
            score.setBonusPoints(timeLeft+currentBonusPoints);

            s2Frame.setVisible(false);
            s3Frame.setVisible(true);

        }

        try {
            section2Questions.next();
            String nextQuestion = section2Questions.getString("Questions");
            section2QuestionBox.setText(nextQuestion);

            s2QuestionNumber++;
            s2QuestionNumberLabel.setText("Question "+s2QuestionNumber+":");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Section1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Error in Next Question method");
        }

    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Section2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Section2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Section2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Section2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Section2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton S2Answer1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton S2Answer2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton S2Answer3;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton S2Answer4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Section2Timer;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JButton nextS2Question;
    private javax.swing.JLabel s2QuestionNumberLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea section2QuestionBox;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Provide the whole stack trace.

Comment: Please add only the relevant code, you cannot expect people to go through the whole thing, and complete stacktrace as well.

Comment: What's with all the fully qualified names?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The very first line in your class `Section2` would cause the problem.

You have, `Section2 s2Frame = new Section2();`, which means, every time an object is created for `Section2` you want to create another object of `Section2` (which will create another object... and sooooooooo on...)

Hence the stackoverflow exception...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly the problem